# Masas in quotients

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a von Neumann algebra and let $B$ be a norm-closed ideal of $A$ (but not necessarily WOT-closed). What one has to assume about $A$ and $B$ to ensure that if $M\subset A$ is a maximal abelian subalgebra, then $M / (B\cap M)$ is a maximal algebian subalgebra of $A/B$? This is the case for $A=B(H)$ and $B=K(H)$.